# How to color table rows with 3 alternate color

Tags: row, css-tables

I want a table to display with 3 alternate colors (1-black,2-red,3-white,4-black, 5-red,6-white ....) i tried with  nth-child(even) and nth-child(odd)
but how to get alternate 3 row colors

Comment: i got it    tr:nth-child(4n-1) {   background-color:#bedc7e !important; }
   tr:nth-child(even) {   background-color:#ffffff !important; }
   tr:nth-child(4n-3) {   background-color:#deedbe !important; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following to the [w3c](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp), you try this:

```
  tr:nth-child(3n+1) {
    background-color: black;
  }
  tr:nth-child(3n+2) {
    background-color: red;
  }
  tr:nth-child(3n) {
    background-color: white;
  }
```

Comment: tr:nth-child(4n-1) { background-color:#bedc7e !important; } tr:nth-child(even) { background-color:#ffffff !important; } tr:nth-child(4n-3) { background-color:#deedbe !important; }              This too works